# Is it possible to listen to any transaction (payment) user makes with a credit card?

Tags: stripe-payments, credit-card, payment-processing

Given user consent, is it possible to listen to any transaction that is made with a credit card previously obtained from the user, by using some payment processor maybe and receiving a web hook event for example?

I was looking through all the events Stripe offers as web hooks although I couldn't find anything similar.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to being informed about all transactions made by a particular credit card on **your** Stripe account - It is possible but you have to implement your own logic to do so.

When a payment method is created, it has a unique id and a fingerprint. The fingerprint uniquely identifies a particular card number. You can use this attribute to check whether two customers who’ve signed up with you are using the same card number. There are some caveats which you can read about here : https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/object#payment_method_object-card-fingerprint

To listen for a transaction(payment) a user makes with a credit card, you would need to know and be alerted based on the PaymentMethod's `card.fingerprint` :

1. You would want to save both the PaymentMethod `id` [0] and its corresponding `card.fingerprint` [1] into your database.
2. You would then want to listen for the `payment_intent.succeeded`[2] event, which would contain the `payment_method`[3] parameter.
3. Based off the `payment_method`[4] parameter in the `payment_intent.succeeded` event, you would check your database if its fingerprint matches what you're "listening" for

[1]https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/object#payment_method_object-card-fingerprint

[2]https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-payment_intent.succeeded

[3]https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object#payment_intent_object-payment_method

[4]https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object#payment_intent_object-payment_method